# How to get fileID from a pdf file from it's URL with google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to write a script which let's users upload files to a specific folder. They would give the URL of the file they upload in a form (the directory link is available in the form where they should upload files). How can i get the file ID from the URL? The next step would be to create a folder that matches the rowID of the submitted form entry and move the file in that folder, set permissions etc. I can create folders but have no idea how to get the fileid from the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file ID is part of the URL. Just strip the parts before and after the id string

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/a/some.domain/file/d/0B0RPFf8VgdL4N2IzN2UyOTItYTfkYy00Y2QwLWL4MWYtOGRiMjQ2OTM5YjUx/edit?usp=sharing';
var fileId = url.replace(/.*\/d\//, '').replace(/\/.*/,  '');
var fileName = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName();
```

Comment: Thanks, just replaced DriveApp with DocsList and it works!
var fileName = DocsList.getFileById(fileId).getName();

Comment: You'll better off using DriveApp - DocsList, which is still "Experimental" will be depreciated in favor of the more powerful DriveApp.

Comment: userx may be referring to this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2772